# White gap on Phonegap pages at bottom

Tags: jquery, android, mobile, cordova, android-virtual-device

I am new on Android with Phonegap development. I am trying to build my first application on eclipse, but my pages are showing an awful white "loading" frame at bottom when I scrolling and I can not remove it.
How can I remove the "loading" white gap on the bottom of my pages?

Comment: I have this exact issue for some reason, building on Win Phone. Did you resolve it?

Comment: @user1066133: You can try to add the jquery.mobile-.css on your page. It was the only way that worked for me on windows.

Comment: I had that one and it was causing that problem. When I switched to the structure one it went away. I'll go from here. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

another solution is to hide the "loading div" that's the white div you see

if you put this code in your Javascript code than you don't see the loading screen any more ;)

```
$.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems developing on Windows Phone 7. Workaround is to set body background-color: #000000;

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem with Cordova 2.3.0 and Windows Phone 8

Solved via adding into css file the following code:

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    @-ms-viewport {
        width: 320px;
        user-zoom: fixed;
        max-zoom: 1;
        min-zoom: 1;
    }
}
```